# Using curl | grep to get the billboard top 200

Tags: curl, grep

Hi I'm trying to grab the billboard top 200 songs / artist.

I understand I need to use 
    `curl http://www.billboard.com/charts/billboard-200 | grep "<h1>" ??`
This grabs the songs for the first page and outputs them but looks pretty ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ for i in {0..9}; do
   saxon-lint --html --xquery '
     for $a in //article[@id]
        let $chart    := $a//span[@class="this-week"]/text()
        let $artist   := normalize-space($a//div[@class="row-title"]/h3/a/text())
        let $song     := normalize-space($a//h2/text())
        let $link     := string($a//div[@class="row-title"]/h3/a/@href)
     return
        concat(
          "[", $chart, "] ", $song, " - ", $artist,
             " : http://www.billboard.com", $link
         )
   ' "http://www.billboard.com/charts/billboard-200?page=$i"
done
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
[1] 1989 - Taylor Swift : http://www.billboard.com/artist/371422/taylor-swift
[2] x - Ed Sheeran : http://www.billboard.com/artist/276089/ed-sheeran
[3] The Pinkprint - Nicki Minaj : http://www.billboard.com/artist/312259/nicki-minaj
...
[200] Take Me Home - One Direction : http://www.billboard.com/artist/314021/one-direction
```

#### NOTE

- Used [saxon-lint](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint) and [xquery](/questions/tagged/xquery)

Comment: Thanks, saxon-lint looks interesting and I like how readable it is for someone who is just getting in to scripting and this sort of stuff

Comment: Yes, it's relatively clear enough. Just need to learn a bit of XPath and XQuery, it's very powerfull.

Comment: I would but I have no rep. I can't seem to get your code to work I get this when executed. `Error on line 2 column 1 
  XPST0003 XQuery syntax error near #.../www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"; for \#:
    Invalid character '\' in expression
Error on line 3 column 5 
  XPST0003 XQuery syntax error near #... let \#:
    Invalid character '\' in expression
Static error(s) in query
Empty String at ./saxon-lint.pl line 68. at ./saxon-lint.pl line 68.
`

Comment: Type : `sed -i 43d saxon-lint.pl`, sorry, I have to fix this (not released at this time)

Comment: I've changed your code to: `saxon-lint --html --xpath '
for $a in //article/header                                              
    let $song := $a/h1/text()
    let $artist   := $a/p[@class="chart_info"]/a/text()
return
concat("artist:", $artist, " song:", $song)' http://www.billboard.com/charts/billboard-200`  it prints a $ about 6 spaces from the end of the lines. Why does it do this

Comment: Are you using windows ? Or which OS ?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu. Also  is there some documentation for how to find what I need to put after the variable. For example let $var := $a/???

Comment: New saxon-lint available. What you typed `???` is a XPath expression, check http://www.balisage.net/Proceedings/vol10/html/Novatchev01/BalisageVol10-Novatchev01.html
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp
http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xpath/info
http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/
http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath
http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/

Comment: Chack XQuery transformation example based on this question: https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint/tree/master/examples/XQuery/billboard.com

Answer (score 0):

Here is some to get you going:

```
curl -silent http://www.billboard.com/charts/billboard-200 | awk -vRS="id=\"rank_" -F"\n" 'NR>1 {split($4,m," *</?h1>");melody=m[2];split($6,a,"\"");artist=a[4];print "("$1+0") "melody " - " artist}'
(1) 1989 - Taylor Swift
(2) x - Ed Sheeran
(3) The Pinkprint - Nicki Minaj
(4) In The Lonely Hour - Sam Smith
(5) SremmLife - Rae Sremmurd
(6) Hozier - Hozier
(7) 2014 Forest Hills Drive - J. Cole
(8) Guardians Of The Galaxy: Awesome Mix Vol. 1 - Soundtrack
(9) FOUR - One Direction
(10) My Everything - Ariana Grande
(11) Into The Woods - Soundtrack
(12) Montevallo - Sam Hunt
(13) Annie - Soundtrack
(14) Greatest Hits: Decade #1 - Carrie Underwood
(15) V - Maroon 5
(16) Frozen - Soundtrack
(17) Old Boots, New Dirt - Jason Aldean
(18) Reclassified - Iggy Azalea
(19) Native - OneRepublic
(20) 1000 Forms Of Fear - Sia
```